# Packing two 8-bit values

Tags: c, arrays, type-conversion

I am stuck with a simple problem.  Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buf[2] = {0xd, 0x1f};
  unsigned int a;

  a = ((buf[1] << 8) & 0xFF00) | buf[0];
  printf("%d\n",a);

  return 0;
}
```

The value in `a` that I need is `0x1FD(509)` but when I ran the above program the output in `a` is `0x1F0D(7949)` .

How can I achieve this ?

EDIT :
Ok let me clarify . I am doing a project where I receive the data as shown in the code snippet.To simplify I have declared them local . The main thing is I want the data to be interpreted as `0x1FD(509)` .

Comment: I don't find it clear what you want to do exactly. Btw @AdamLiss, I know about the shift-and-or method, but I don't think it's clear what Leo tries to do. If you need 509, why write 0xd, 0x1f?  Why not use an integer value or array instead? What problem is this code trying to solve?

Comment: Leo, is @dasblinkenlight on the right track?

Comment: do you just want to pack (ignore zeros) the Hex values?

Comment: Reading through the answers, there seems to be some confusion.  Do you want the answer to be packed so that the four most significant bits in `0x0d` are removed (as per your "expected" output), or do you simply want the two bytes to be packed in the least significant 16 bits of a?

Comment: Just to confirm : Input cannot be changed ...

Comment: How would you represent `0x1F0D` in the `buf` array?

Comment: @Roee : The trick should work for both .. What I mean is if buf[0] = 0xD or buf[0] = 0x1D ;

Answer (score 6):

The program does what you asked it to do. The source of your confusion is in the `0xd` constant, which is actually `0x0d`, because `char` is eight bits. Packing it together with `0x1f` as you do should produce `0x1f0d`, and it does.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : That's what I tried assuming that it works.I want the output to be 0x1FD

Comment: @LeoMessi What would you like to do with the top four bits of `0x0D` then? For example, if `buf[2] = {0xad, 0x1f}`, what is your expected output?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : 0x1FAD(8109)

Comment: @LeoMessi if `{0xad, 0x1f}` is packed as `0x1FAD`, why shouldn't `{0x0d, 0x1f}` pack as `0x1F0D` then? Dropping leading zero of `0x0d` is not possible, because you wouldn't be able to distinguish the output from the encoded `{0x01, 0xfd}` then.

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
char buf[2] = {0xfd, 0x01};
```

That is, you need to "pack" the bits from right to left.

This is clearer if you pad the desired value with zeroes, so it's written as a string of complete bytes:

`0x1FD` = `0x01FD` = `(0x01 << 8) | 0xFD`

Comment: The OP doesn't want to change his input, he wants to get a different output.

Comment: @Richard: we don't really know that, do we.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I'll take that bet.  I've learned from too many years filling in for Tech Support that sometimes you need to debug the developer before you can debug the code.  :-)

Comment: You could have been more verbose, but after reading dasblinkenlight answer I understood yours too. Upvoting both.

Comment: @Richard : you are right .. Cannot change the input ..With given input I need 0x1FD(509)

Answer (score 2):

A char is 8 bits, hence it is represented by two hexadecimal *digits*.

If you want `0x1FD` in your variable `a`, then you should initialize the array with `0xfd` and `0x01`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the empty bits:

```
unsigned pack(char bytes[2])
{
    char shift = 8;
    if (bytes[0] < 32)
        shift = 4;

    return (unsigned) ((bytes[1] << shift) | bytes[0]);
}
```

Comment: You should compare to 32, not 128. But most of all, it is completely misleading with respect to the OP question.

Comment: @DidierTrosset you are correct, I should have compared to 32. However, the OP stated that what he wanted was to pack it so that it got the result he wanted, not to change the input to get the output he wanted. This adapts to both situations quite adequately.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII : Looks right but what if bytes[0] = 0x2F; ..Then it will not work

Comment: @LeoMessi what do you expect it to output? For me, the output is `1F2F`.